# double byte character sequence conversion issue in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, character-encoding, visual-studio-2015, locale

I am trying to convert double byte character sequence (DBCS) in CP936 to `wchar_t` using C++ locale. This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

// 国 in CP936
char const src[] = "\xB9\xFA";

int main()
{
    std::locale loc(".936");
    typedef std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t> codecvt_type;
    codecvt_type const & cvt = std::use_facet<codecvt_type>(loc);

    std::mbstate_t state;
    std::memset(&state, 0, sizeof(state));

    char const * src_mid = src;
    wchar_t buf[10];
    wchar_t * buf_mid = buf;

    std::codecvt_base::result res = cvt.in(state,
        src, src + 2, src_mid,
        buf, buf + 10, buf_mid);
    int eno = errno;
    std::cout << "res: " << +res << "\n"
        << "errno: " << eno << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Now, the conversion always ends with error and `errno` set to 42, which is `EILSEQ`. I have debugged the code and I think I can see what goes wrong but I do not understand why.

What goes wrong is that the code that ultimately leads to call to `MultiByteToWideChar()`, has a conditional like this:

```
if ( ploc->_Isleadbyte[ch >> 3] & (1 << (ch & 7)) )
```

This branch is never taken, despite the fact that the source string AFAIK contains correct lead byte and trailing byte. I have checked the `_Isleadbyte` array in debugger and it is all zeroes. So this branch which sets the input length to `2` is never taken and instead the one where length is set to `1` is taken and thus the `MultiByteToWideChar()` fails because lead byte has to be accompanied by trailing byte.

I have even checked that `C_936.NLS` is present in `C:\Windows\System32\`, so that should not be the problem.

So, I guess the question is: Is this issue on my end, with the test code, with Windows OS setup, missing components? Or is this issue in the Visual Studio 2015 code?

**UPDATE**

So I have incidentally stumbled upon this question:[Shift-JIS decoding fails using wifstrem in Visual C++ 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618463/shift-jis-decoding-fails-using-wifstrem-in-visual-c-2013)

The OPs own answer shows a workaround:

```
const int oldMbcp = _getmbcp();
_setmbcp(932);
const std::locale locale("Japanese_Japan.932");
_setmbcp(oldMbcp);
```

The same workaround seems to work for the CP936 that I am trying to use.

**UPDATE 2**

I filed a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1925650) with Microsoft.

Comment: MultiByteToWideChar(936, 0, src, -1, buf, 10);  Bam, done, no problems.

Comment: @HansPassant: Well, I do not want to use that function but the C++ locale facilities. :)